# Bash expr with 0 before decimals

Tags: bash, decimal

I am summing two small decimal numbers contained in two variables:

```
SEEupper=`expr $SEEmedian+$SEEthre | bc`
```

but since the result is a number smaller than 1, like 0.XXXX, the output is: '.XXXX'.
Is there any way to have an output with the '0' before the dot and the decimals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

workaround: `... | sed -e "s|^\.|0.|"`

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work for negative numbers...

Comment: `... | sed -e "s|^\(-\?\)\.|\10.|"`

Answer (score 0):

if you can use python:

```
SEEupper=`python -c "print $SEEmedian +$SEEthre"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the internal bash command `printf`:

```
printf "%g" $SEEupper
```